# Display two different values from different columns of same row in autocoompleteextender

Tags: c#, asp.net, autocompleteextender

I am using autocompleteextender in my asp.net website. It is working fine. I want additional functionality when user types it shows suggestion like below

suppose I type P in textbox
Result - PNQ , PAR, PBC etc

Here evry keyword has fullform in second column so I want data to display like this

PNQ (Pune Airport)

When this value get selected by user then should only select PNQ in textbox not entire value i.e PNQ (Pune Airport). This I want becuase users should get clear what they are selecting. Can anyone help me in this.

```
 <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="SearchClientCode"
 ServicePath="~/myadmin/shipments-profile.aspx" MinimumPrefixLength="1"
 OnClientShown="resetPosition" CompletionInterval="100" EnableCaching="false"
 CompletionSetCount="10" TargetControlID="clientCode" ID="clientCodeExtender"
 runat="server" FirstRowSelected="false" CompletionListCssClass="completionList"
 CompletionListItemCssClass="listItem"
 CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="itemHighlighted"></asp:AutoCompleteExtender>


[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(), System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
public static List<string> SearchClientCode(string prefixText, int count)
{
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString;
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT clientID, clientName FROM clientsDetails where (clientID like @SearchText)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText + "%");
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    conn.Open();
    List<string> customers = new List<string>();
    MySqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader;
    while (sdr.Read) {
        customers.Add(sdr("clientID").ToString);
    }
    conn.Close();
    return customers;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some client side functions and change in webmethod to accomplish your requirements

**Html:**

Hook up two events **OnClientPopulated** and **OnClientItemSelected** and set **BehaviorID** to control.

```
<asp:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="SearchClientCode" ServicePath="~/myadmin/shipments-profile.aspx" MinimumPrefixLength="1" OnClientShown="resetPosition" CompletionInterval="100" EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="10" TargetControlID="clientCode" ID="clientCodeExtender" runat="server" FirstRowSelected="false" CompletionListCssClass="completionList" CompletionListItemCssClass="listItem" CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="itemHighlighted" OnClientPopulated="onClientPopulated" OnClientItemSelected="itemSelected" BehaviorID="AutoCompleteEx"></asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function itemSelected(ev)
  {
    var index=$find("AutoCompleteEx")._selectIndex;
    if(index!=-1) {
   $find("AutoCompleteEx").get_element().value =$find("AutoCompleteEx").get_completionList().childNodes[index]._value;
  }
 else{
  $find("AutoCompleteEx").get_element().value = '';   
 }
}

function onClientPopulated(sender,e)
{
  var List=$find("AutoCompleteEx").get_completionList();
  for(i=0;i<List.childNodes.length;i++)
   {
     var _value=JSON.parse(List.childNodes[i]._value);
     var abbr=_value[0];
     var fullform =_value[1];
     List.childNodes[i]._value=abbr;
     List.childNodes[i].innerHTML="<span>"+ abbr + "("+fullform+")</span>"
   }  }</script>
```

**webmethod:**

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(), System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
public static List<string> SearchClientCode(string prefixText, int count)   
 {
   MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();
   conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString;
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT clientID, clientName FROM clientsDetails where (clientID like @SearchText)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText + "%");
cmd.Connection = conn;
conn.Open();
List<string> customers = new List<string>();
MySqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader;
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
while (sdr.Read) {
    object[] item = new object[] { sdr("clientID").ToString(), sdr("clientName").ToString() };
    customers.Add(serializer.Serialize(item));
}
conn.Close();
return customers;}
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: When user select any value then it should only take ID not entire string. That is what my main problem which still not solved

Comment: @SUN i have updated itemSelected function to select the ID value. Please check

Comment: When I am selecting any item it inserts this "[" Open square bracket

Comment: can you please share me your code, so that I can have the look?

Comment: My code looks exactly same as you given. And rest I have given on post. Do you want to see the output?

Comment: Please see this demo link I made http://orionexpresslogistics.com/auto.aspx

Comment: @SUN I have updated onClientPopulated function, JSON.parse is required to parse the value. Still let me know if you face the issue, we are almost close to solution :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132957/discussion-between-sun-and-jayakrishnan-gounder).

Comment: Hi Jay I need your help. Please ping me.

Comment: Sorry Jay I have to unmark this as correct answer as it still has selection issue.